# How to make contingency table from another contingency table using count values of the first contingency table?

Tags: python, pandas, contingency

Using pandas dataframes I construct all the contingency tables from each feature of the zoo dataset. The contingency table looks like.

```
Domestic  Catsize  Type  Count
0            0       1     7
0            0       2     11
0            0       3     4
0            0       4     8
0            0       5     4
0            0       6     7
0            0       7     9
0            1       1     26
1            0       2     3
1            1       1     6
```

Now, I want to create other contingency tables from this table where the values of the contingency tables are the values from the Count column. For Example, a contingency table for  Type =1 would look like this (Type (T),Domestic (D) and Catsize (C))

```
         T       T`
      -----------------
DC    |  6    |   0   |
      -----------------
(DC)` |  33   |   46  |
      -----------------
```

The output table containing the values are calculated as: For example: the value 33 is calculated as when ANDing Domestic and Catsize value gives 0 (such as combinations 0 AND 1, 1 AND 0, and 0 AND 0) and Type =1, there are two records with count=7 and count=26. The sum of these values results in 33. Similarly, the combinations 0 AND 1, 1 AND 0, and 0 AND 0 with Type not equal to 1 (2,3,4,5,6,7), there are 7 records and their counts are added (11+4+8+4+7+9+3) providing the value 46 in the bottom right cell.

The same calculations needs to be done for Type=2 and 3 and so on.

Any help in this regards will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
df.pivot_table(index=['Type', 'Domestic'], columns=['Catsize'], values='Count')
```

**Output**

```
Catsize           0     1
Type Domestic            
1    0          7.0  26.0
     1          NaN   6.0
2    0         11.0   NaN
     1          3.0   NaN
3    0          4.0   NaN
4    0          8.0   NaN
5    0          4.0   NaN
6    0          7.0   NaN
7    0          9.0   NaN
```

Comment: Actually i wanted to get the values in such form that if the combinations of Catsize and Domestic is equal to zero and Type is not 1 then the specific column for (DC)` and T` must have the sum of all the count values where the combination of Catsize and Domestic is equal to zero and Type is other than 1. In the above contingency table of the question the value for (DC)` and T` column is 46 (11+4+8+4+7+9+3)

Comment: @eshfaqahmad its still not clear what you are asking. please update question with exact expected output